# Reemplazar datos invalidos

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy trabajando en un input que solo puede aceptar

- Números
- Letra K (mayuscula o minuscula)
- guion medio (-)

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular `/^[Kk0-9-]+$/` para hacer que solo estos tipos de datos sean aceptados. Lo que necesito es que cada vez que el usuario escriba en este input cualquier otro dato que no sea valido se borre.

Tengo el evento `ng-change` la función :

```
$scope.changeRutCliente = function(){
   if ($scope.rut_cliente.match(/^[Kk0-9-]+$/)) {
       console.log('is valid');
   } else {
       console.log('invalid');
   }
}
```

Pero no he podido lograr hacer que borre los datos invalidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me respondo solo xD, encontré que cuando se antepone un `^` a la expresión regular, los niega

entonces quedaria asi :

```
$scope.rut_cliente = $scope.rut_cliente.replace(/[^Kk0-9-]+$/, "");
```